# How if use IFNA in VBA (combined with Index/Match)

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have two sheets. One is called “Exclusions”, the other one is called “PCAM Commitments.” Exclusions sheet ONLY contains the projects with a status of “Exclude”. PCAM Commitments sheet have all the projects (so both “Include” and “Exclude” projects).
[Exclusions Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VX17.png); [PCAM Commitments Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qb5E.png)

I need to match these Exclude/Include values in Column G of the PCAM Commitments sheet. Since projects with a status of “Include” are not on the “Exclusions” sheet, I need to use IFNA function.

This formula will do the job:
=IFNA(INDEX(Exclusions!B2:C100, MATCH('PCAM Commitments'!A2,Exclusions!B2:B100,0),2), "Include")

But I am having troubles to convert this formula to vba code.

```
Sub ExIn()

Dim i As Integer
Dim lookRange As Range
Dim StartRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Integer

Dim ID As Long
Dim Value As Long

ID = Application.Match("PO/SO", Rows(1), 0)
Value = Application.Match("Ex/In", Rows(1), 0)

LastRow = Sheets("PCAM Commitments").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set lookRange = Sheets("Exclusions").Range("B2:C136")
Set StartRange = Sheets("Exclusions").Range("B2:B136")


For i = 2 To LastRow
    Worksheets("PCAM Commitments").Cells(i, Value) = WorksheetFunction.IfNa(WorksheetFunction.Index(lookRange, WorksheetFunction.Match(Worksheets("PCAM Commitments").Cells(i, ID).Value, StartRange, 0), 2), "Include")

Next i

End Sub
```

This is what I have now. Whenever I run it, an error message will pop up saying “Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class…. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Match` will throw that error if no match. One alternative is to use `Application.Match` and then test if the result is an error with `IsError`.

Comment: You mean like this: " Worksheets("PCAM Commitments").Cells(i, Value) = WorksheetFunction.IsError(WorksheetFunction.Index(lookRange, Application.Match(Worksheets("PCAM Commitments").Cells(i, ID).Value, StartRange, 0), 2), "Include") "?...It's not working either

Comment: Not `WorksheetFunction.IsError`, but the [`IsError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/iserror-function) function. You'll need to split this out into multiple lines.

Comment: Another option is to use `Evaluate` with your original formula.

Comment: In my opinion, the best option will be to get rid of long `WorksheetFunction` and use other vba tools. Do I understand correctly that you need to go through sheet PCAM Commitments, take a pair of values from columns A and B, find same pair on Exclusions sheet in columns C and B, and fill the column G of PCAM Commitments sheet appropriately?

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak Yes. Except on PCAM Commitments, I only need to care about column A. So, I need to find Column A (of PCAM Commitments) values in Column B of Exclusions, then fill the column G of PCAM Commitments with corresponding values from Columns C of Exclusions. If a value doesn't exist, then I want it automatically show as "Include" in Column G.

Comment: Why not just use the formula?

Comment: @SJR long story in short, I have to use Alteryx for data transferring, and Alteryx will erase formulas in its overwriting process, so I have to use VBA

Comment: @VitaliyPrushak What do you mean other vba tools?

Comment: Load everything into variant arrays, output to a variant array and loop those.

Comment: @EmmaG see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with Vlookup and Application instead of Worksheetfunction,like this:

```
With Application
For i = 2 To LastRow
    Worksheets("PCAM Commitments").Cells(i, Value) = .IfNa(.VLookup(Worksheets("PCAM Commitments").Cells(i, ID).Value, lookRange, 2, False), "Include")
Next i
End With
```